# Probability of picking the same ball during 3 groups of multiple picks?

Tags: probability

The real situation:
Three reviewers each picked their favorites from among 117 different entries.
One reviewer picked 15 favorites, while the other two picked 10 each.
Each reviewer picked from all 117 entries.
It turned out that 0 entries were picked by all three reviewers, 7 were picked by at least two reviewers.

I'm trying to get a sense of the reviewers "performance" compared to random selection.  I.e.:

There are 117 uniquely numbered balls.
One person picks 15 balls from the 117.
A second person picks 10 balls from all 117.
A third person picks 10 balls from all 117.
What is the expected value of the number of balls picked by all three people?
What is the expected value of the number of balls picked by at least two people?

I'm sorry I don't have any progress to show.  It's been over a decade since I took statistics and I just don't remember much.  Thank you much for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linearity of Expectation is good for this sort of thing.

How many do we expect to be chosen by all $3$?  Call that number $E_3$.  Well, let $X_i$ be the indicator for each.  That $X_i$=1 if the $i^{th}$ entry is chosen by all $3$.  Linearity tells us that $$E_3=E[\sum X_i]=\sum E[X_i]$$
But $E[X_i]$ is just the probability that $i$ is chosen by all three which, under uniform randomness, is given by $$E[X_i]=\frac {15}{117}\times \frac {10}{117}\times \frac {10}{117}=0.000936556\implies \boxed {E_3=0.109577033}$$
So not seeing any of those is hardly surprising.

How many do we expect to be seen by exactly $2$? Call that number $E_2$.  Let $Y_i$ be the indicator variable in this case. Again we get $$E_2=117\times E[Y_i]$$  But $E[Y_i]$ is slightly harder to compute.  It's still the probability that $i$ is chosen by exactly $2$ reviewers but now there are multiple ways to get there.  Let the reviewers be $(A,B,C)$ with $A$ the one that picks $15$.  The probability that $i$ is chosen by $(A,B)$ but not $C$ is $\frac {15}{117}\times \frac {10}{117}\times \frac {107}{117}=0.010021147$.  This is also the probability that $i$ is chosen by $(A,C)$ but not $B$.  The probability that $i$ is chosen by $(B,C)$ but not $A$ is $\frac {102}{117}\times \frac {10}{117}\times \frac {10}{117}=0.00636858$.  Thus $$E[Y_i]=2\times 0.010021147+0.00636858=0.026410875\implies \boxed {E_2=3.090072321}$$  Thus, you'd expect to see only $3$.  I'd say $7$ was very surprising indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $1\{B_i\}$ be an indicator random variable that denotes if the ith ball has been picked by all three people. Define $N = \sum_{i=1}^{117} 1\{B_i\}$. Thus, by linearity of expectation, $\mathbb{E}[N] = \sum_{i=1}^{117} \mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is chosen by all three people}]$.

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is chosen by all three people}] &= \mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is chosen by person 1}] \times \mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is chosen by person 2}] \times \mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is chosen by person 3}]
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is chosen by person 1}] &= 1 - \mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is not chosen by person 1}] = 1 - \frac{\binom{116}{15}}{\binom{117}{15}}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is chosen by person 2}] &= 1 - \mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is not chosen by person 1}] = 1 - \frac{\binom{116}{10}}{\binom{117}{10}}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is chosen by person 3}] &= 1 - \mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is not chosen by person 1}] = 1 - \frac{\binom{116}{10}}{\binom{117}{10}}
\end{align}

Proceed similarly in the other case. $$\mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is chosen by at least two people}] = \mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is chosen by all three people}] + \mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is chosen by exactly two people}]$$

You already know how to do $\mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is chosen by all three people}]$.

\begin{align}
&\mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is chosen by exactly two people}] \\
&= \left(\mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is chosen by person 1}] \times \mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is chosen by person 2}] \times \mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is not chosen by person 3}]\right) \\ 
&+ \left(\mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is chosen by person 1}] \times \mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is chosen by person 3}] \times \mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is not chosen by person 2}]\right) \\
&+ \left(\mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is chosen by person 3}] \times \mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is chosen by person 2}] \times \mathbb{P}[\text{ith ball is not chosen by person 1}]\right)
\end{align}